# How to open HTML properly in WinSCP

Tags: ssh, winscp

I am trying to use WinSCP to access a remote HTML file, and I do have root permission. However, if I open that HTML, it seems that all the sources and scripts are dysfunctional, e.g no images, buttons etc are loaded, and no js functions work. So how can I open a HTML using WinSCP so that all the sources are loaded and work properly? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you want WinSCP to show rendered page instead of opening its code in editor? Or open the page in a local webbrowser?

Comment: I want to open a rendered page in webbrowser, and it's always a dysfunctional page (no image, js functions not working). So how can I open that page that works well?

Comment: So you "Open" the HTML file from a remote panel of WinSCP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you "Open" the HTML file from a remote panel of WinSCP.

This makes WinSCP download the file to a temporary local folder and open the file from there.

As all the references to images and java script files are typically relative paths, they won't work from the temporary folder as the referenced files are not there. So it cannot work.

---

Either you need to download all files (including images and .js) to a local folder and open the HTML there.

---

Or you actually want to open the file from the server, via HTTP.

For that use the [WinSCP extension "Generate HTTP URL"](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/extension_generate_http_url).

Comment: Thanks a lot, open via HTTP works, and WinSCP temporarily download the file so it would work on WinSCP